# Error when trying to visualize report

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to sum the values of two specific labels using a script in xtrareports. The script is not the problem, the problem is the moment when I try to visualize the report. I get the next error's: [image: Xtrareport script error]

I don't know if i missing something.
My script code is this:

```
private void lblSaldo_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) 
{
   double A = double.Parse(CargoTotal.Text);
   double B = double.Parse(AbonoTotal.Text);
   double C = A-B;  
   lblSaldo.Text = C.ToString();
}
```

I know the error's are because there is a ";" missing somewhere, but I don't know where. Also if i delete the code I post above, I can see my report again.

I'm using the DevExpress DocumentViewer.
The version of DevExpress I use is the 14.1 in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The error says specifically what line and column it's happening at.

Comment: Yeah i know, the problem in happens, that those lines of code are no where to be found in my document.
Also if i delete the script the report visualize correctly